# Int 10 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, int

So as I understand it an int in SQL Server is automatically set to a length of 4 digits. A bigint has a default length of 8. It seems these cannot be made any other length, so what do you do when you want a column that will only contain digits and you need it to be a length of 10?

I already tried float and while it will store the 10 digits it does so in scientific notation.

Comment: "Scientific notation" is not a property of the `float` data type. It is a way of displaying it on the screen. Also you seem to be confusing number of bytes required to store a binary value and number of digits its textual representation has.

Comment: That is what I thought, actually. It should take up to ten digits. But I get an arithmetic overflow error when I try to add the number.

Comment: @MarcelMarino 4 [signed] bytes is limited to 2,147,483,647.  You can't store all 10 digit base-10 values with a 32-bit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` takes 4 *bytes* (-2^31 to 2^31 - 1), and `bitint` takes 8 *bytes* (-2^64 to 2^64 - 1).  They're 32-bit and 64-bit signed integers, respectively.

Please refer to the [data type documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848794.aspx).

Additionally, you should avoid `float` and `real` unless you really need them, as they're approximate number types.  `decimal` or `numeric` are preferred for decimal values.

If you want the equivalent of an "INT(10)", then you should use `decimal(10)`, which will support -9999999999 to 9999999999.  Bear in mind that this will use more disk space than a `bigint` (9 bytes), and may perform differently at very large scales.

Comment: I'm just adding in a 10 digit telephone number. The 4 bytes should take ten digits, but I get an arithmetic overflow error when I try to add the telephone number.

Comment: @MarcelMarino you should use varchar for phone numbers. You aren't going to be doing math against various phone numbers.

Comment: What about for auto-incremented primary keys? Still use varchar? This database could easily get to the 7 figures as far as records go.

Comment: @MarcelMarino Use `bigint` if you think 32-bit isn't enough for your identity columns.  You will not run out of 64-bit numbers.

Comment: @MarcelMarino you can't auto-increment a varchar.

Comment: @MarcelMarino, you accepted this answer... Are you going to store your phone numbers in `DECIMAL(10)` now?

Comment: @BaconBits As the OP accepted this, you should maybe add some hint, that phone numbers should not be stored in a numeric field at all - for future readers...

Comment: @Shnugo, No I"m going with varchar as Sean Lange said (gave him an upvote too). Voted this up because it iwas descriptive and contained the comment with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the concept of a human readable number (the common digits) with its digital representation (bits).

`INT` which takes 4 Bytes (32 bit) is not at its end at "9999"... There are 4.294.967.295 different values possible with an int...

From other comments I take, that you want to store phone numbers...

Take this as a general rule: Store in numeric fields values, which you want to use in mathematical computations.

Would you ever think that a phone number +2 or a phonenumber divided by 4 does make any sense?

Anyway: Very often phonenumbers are stored with some kind of delimiters.

Put this all together and you come to the conclusion: no DECIMAL(10), no INT, no BIGINT but VARCHAR(50) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of sql server are you using. I am using sql server 2014. There is a datatype decimal in it. It does what you want. If it is available in your sql server try it.